# JPype class not found

Tags: java, python, jvm, jpype

JPype is an amazing project since I allows to instantiate a `JVM` directly from `Python`.

Unfortunately, I got stuck in the first baby steps.

I have `A.java` source code (**`located in C:\tmp folder`**):

```
class A {
    public A() {
        super();
    }
    public String sayHi() {
        return("Hello");
    }
}
```

Which was compiled to a class, using: `javac A.java`

Thus, A.class is located in **`C:\tmp`** folder.

I have the following `Python` source code:

```
import os
import jpype
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), '-ea', '-Djava.class.path=c:\\tmp')
A = jpype.JClass("A")
a = A()
print a.sayHi()
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

When I run it, I get the error below:

```
C:\tmp>jpype_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tmp\jpype_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    A = jpype.JClass("A")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jclass.py", line 54, in JClass
    raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name)
jpype._jexception.ExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.Exception: Class A not found
```

Since I can't find the A class, it is probably an issue related to CLASSPATH, but I can't realize what I am doing wrong.

Any clues?

**EDIT 1:**

The problem persists. But, just to add to my question, if I use native java libraries, like: java.util, the code runs WITHOUT errors. For example, the code below works:

```
import jpype
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())
util = jpype.JPackage("java.util")
al = util.ArrayList()
al.add(1)
al.add(2)
print al.size()
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

And returns 2.

**EDIT 2:**

Issue solved, see answer below...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem and I would let the answer here for the records.

1) **Nothing was wrong with the source code.**

2) Problem was that my `Python` was 32 bits and my `java sdk` (including the javac bytecode compiler) was 64 bits. I uninstalled the `java sdk` and re-installed a 32bits version. Done! Solved!

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your path like this:

```
    jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), '-ea', '-Djava.class.path=c:\\tmp\')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use your path with one `\` instead of two `\` and also the root of the Windows platform with a capitalized `C` as in:

```
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=C:\tmp\A.jar")
```

In my case, it worked.

**Important notes:**

- I have a JDK 11 and Python 3.9.6, both in 64 bits.
- You could create a jar file that packages the class A.
- You could check for the number of bits of Python you have installed by executing the following command in your command line:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.maxsize > 2**32)"
```