# TypeError: _init_() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, jvm

I am newbie to python & want to run simple code to create & save HelloWorld.docx
here is my code of default.py

```
asd = os.path.join(os.path.abspath("./"), "lib")
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.ext.dirs=%s" % asd)
hw = HelloWorld()
hw.main()
```

And here is my code of *init*.py()

```
class HelloWorld:
def __init__(self, dataDir):
    self.dataDir = dataDir

def main(self):
    """
        : The path to the documents directory. :
    """
    Document = jpype.JClass("com.aspose.words.Document")

    DocumentBuilder = jpype.JClass("com.aspose.words.DocumentBuilder")

    doc = Document()
    builder = DocumentBuilder(doc)

    builder.writeln('Hello World!')
    doc.save(self.dataDir +'HelloWorld.docx')
```

I am getting this error "TypeError: *init*() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" I don't know how to fix it, I double check on everywhere but nothing prove helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the variable dataDir here:

```
hw = HelloWorld('path/to/your/dir')
```

Comment: @UsamaSaeed: what is `dataDir` variable? means which value you are going to store in this variable

Comment: Now Error changes to jpype.JClass("com.aspose.words.Document") class not found, did you know how to solve it??

Answer (score 0):

By definition, **init** of your class Helloworld needs a value for dataDir.

But when instantiating you didn't supply any.

Building on the answers above, can you check if the error regarding missing class is the same in this link?

[JPype class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430466/jpype-class-not-found-solved)

Answer (score 0):

When we create object of class, the `__init__` function is called. the `__init__` function accept two argument, one is class instance `self` and other is `dataDir`.

**`__init__` will initializes an instance of a class, or an object.**

**The `__init__` function is called a constructor, or initialiser, and is automatically called when you create a new instance of a class.**

- More about [classes in Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)
- More about the [`__init__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)

Comment: Yeah I know that but what I can add in 
obj = HelloWorld()

Comment: what is dataDir variable? means which value you are going to store in this variable.  OR  Remove  ` dataDir` paramenter from the `__init__` function