# Class not found .jar file is not loaded in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jar, aspose-cells, jpype

I am unable to load .jar file for my python code, Here is my code for default.py

```
from quickstart import HelloWorld
import jpype
import os.path

path =os.path.join("/home/nhp06/Documents/Aspose_Cells_java_for_Python/src/lib/aspose-cells-8.6.3.jar")
dataDir = os.path.join(os.path.abspath("./"), "tests/")

jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.ext.dirs=%s" % path)

hw = HelloWorld(dataDir)
hw.main()

shutdownJVM()
```

And here is my code for **init**.py

```
import jpype

class HelloWorld:

def __init__(self,dataDir):

    self.dataDir = dataDir
    self.Workbook = jpype.JClass("com.aspose.cells.Workbook")
    self.FileFormatType = jpype.JClass("com.aspose.cells.FileFormatType")

def main(self):

    workbook = self.Workbook()

    sheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0)

    cell = sheet.getCells().get("A1")

    cell.setValue("Hello World!")

    file_format_type = self.FileFormatType

    workbook.save(self.dataDir + "HelloWorld.xls" , file_format_type.EXCEL_97_TO_2003 )

    print "Document has been saved, please check the output file.";
```

When I try to run the above code I get the error

"raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name)
jpype._jexception.ExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.Exception: Class com.aspose.cells.Workbook not found"

I am unable to figure this out, why this error occur. I double check my path for .jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue might be related to classpath, so you should figure it out on your end. See the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430466/jpype-class-not-found-solved) for your reference.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Yeah it is, I fix it long ago.
I forget to share my answer :)